# Control un-matching quotes and parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, quoting

I want to control some special characters and un-matching quoting/parenthesis in an HTML Form. I have two types of text area elements:

A single one:

```
<textarea rows=10 cols=10> text enter by user </textarea>
```

and the second are compose of many:

```
<textarea name='comment1' rows=10 cols=10> text1 enter by user </textarea>
<textarea name='comment2' rows=10 cols=10> text2 enter by user </textarea>
```

These two textareas are used to update a database, and so in this database I don't want % and & character. For this I used regular expression in the pattern attribute, e.g.:

```
<textarea rows=10 cols=10 pattern=[^%&]> text enter by user </textarea>
```

but I don't want any un-matching quote (simple or double) and no unbalanced parenthesis. I want to do this task in Javascript (or Jquery).

Comment: *"in this database I don't want % and & character"* - Why not?  This requirement alludes to a possible SQL injection vulnerability that isn't being addressed.  If that's the case, blacklisting characters will not correct that problem.

Comment: Yes, this html form is used after by SAS (and SQL) for updating a database and in SAS, % correspond to macrofunction, & to macro variable. But blacklisting this character in SAS is not complicated but the unmatching quotation and unbalanced parenthesis in the same time is impossible. So i want to control it before processing.